# How to calculate sum for group of dynamic table rows in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my JSFiddle/Code Snippet(Just an example, mine is a dynamic table)

I have three Groups - CAPITAL, FIXED ASSET & CURRENT ASSET (pink color), The row will be child(white color) if no other row under it. If the row has another row under it, then it will become a parent(orange color).

Users only can input value in the child. The total value of the child in the group will show at the rows of group and parent(if have)
**Rows that have color background cannot insert value

I want to calculate the total amount based on the group and the grand total amount. For now, I only success calculate the grand total amount as shown in my JS Fiddle or code snippet. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eof3w7kg/2/)
I do not have any idea on how to calculate based on group condition for the table and calculate up the amount. Does anyone have an idea??

Result that I expected:
[image]

This is the current result that I get:

[image]

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.dr-amount, .cr-amount', function(e) {
  var dr = 0;
  cr = 0;
  total_cr = 0,
    total_dr = 0;
  $(".acc-row").each(function() {
    total_dr += $(this).find(".dr-amount").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".dr-amount").val()) : 0
    console.log(total_dr)
    total_cr += $(this).find(".cr-amount").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".cr-amount").val()) : 0
  })
  $(".dr-total").val(total_dr.toFixed(2))
  $(".cr-total").val(total_cr.toFixed(2))
});
```

```css
table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.level0 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.level1 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.level2 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.level3 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.level4 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 130px;
}

.level5 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 160px;
}

.closed td:first-child::before {
  content: "+";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>DR</th>
      <th>CR</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:pink">
      <td class="accType">CAPITAL</td>
      <td><input class="groupdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="groupcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 acc-row">
      <td>CAPITAL CONTRIBUTION </td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:pink">
      <td class="accType">FIXED ASSETS</td>
      <td><input class="groupdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="groupcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 acc-row">
      <td>BUILDING</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 acc-row">
      <td>ACCUM. DPN-BUILDING</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 acc-row">
      <td>COMPUTER</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:orange">
      <td>ACCUM. DPN-COMPUTER</td>
      <td><input class="parentdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="parentcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="3" class="collapse level3 acc-row">
      <td>DPN-COMPUTER 1</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="3" class="collapse level3 acc-row">
      <td>DPN-COMPUTER 2</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:pink">
      <td class="accType">CURRENT ASSETS</td>
      <td><input class="groupdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="groupcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:orange">
      <td>INVESTMENT</td>
      <td><input class="parentdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="parentcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2 acc-row">
      <td>INVESTMENT IN ABC COMPANY</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:orange">
      <td>OTHER INVESTMENT</td>
      <td><input class="parentdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="parentcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2 acc-row">
      <td>OTHER INVESTMENT-ABC COMP</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0" style="background-color:blue">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><input class="dr-total" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="cr-total" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Still having problems?

Comment: No more, tried just now and it works. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following function to your code, it should work as you want.

```
function parentRowCalc() {
  $(".parent-acc-row").each(function() {
    var level = $(this).attr("class").match(/level\d+/)[0];
    var childs = $(this).nextUntil(".parent-acc-row." + level);
    if (childs.length > 0) {
      var numb1 = 0,
        numb2 = 0;
      childs.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("parent-acc-row")) {
          numb1 += +$(this).find("input:eq(0)").val() || 0
          numb2 += +$(this).find("input:eq(1)").val() || 0
        }
      });
      if (numb1 > 0) $(this).find("input:eq(0)").val(numb1);
      if (numb2 > 0) $(this).find("input:eq(1)").val(numb2);
    }
  });
}
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.dr-amount, .cr-amount', function(e) {
  var dr = 0;
  cr = 0;
  total_cr = 0,
    total_dr = 0;
  $(".acc-row").each(function() {
    total_dr += $(this).find(".dr-amount").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".dr-amount").val()) : 0
    console.log(total_dr)
    total_cr += $(this).find(".cr-amount").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".cr-amount").val()) : 0
  })
  parentRowCalc();
  $(".dr-total").val(total_dr.toFixed(2))
  $(".cr-total").val(total_cr.toFixed(2))
});

function parentRowCalc() {
  $(".parent-acc-row").each(function() {
    var level = $(this).attr("class").match(/level\d+/)[0];
    var childs = $(this).nextUntil(".parent-acc-row." + level);
    if (childs.length > 0) {
      var numb1 = 0,
        numb2 = 0;
      childs.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("parent-acc-row")) {
          numb1 += +$(this).find("input:eq(0)").val() || 0
          numb2 += +$(this).find("input:eq(1)").val() || 0
        }
      });
      if (numb1 > 0) $(this).find("input:eq(0)").val(numb1);
      if (numb2 > 0) $(this).find("input:eq(1)").val(numb2);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.level0 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.level1 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.level2 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.level3 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.level4 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 130px;
}

.level5 td:first-child {
  padding-left: 160px;
}

.closed td:first-child::before {
  content: "+";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>DR</th>
      <th>CR</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:pink">
      <td class="accType">CAPITAL</td>
      <td><input class="groupdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="groupcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 acc-row">
      <td>CAPITAL CONTRIBUTION </td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:pink">
      <td class="accType">FIXED ASSETS</td>
      <td><input class="groupdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="groupcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 acc-row">
      <td>BUILDING</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 acc-row">
      <td>ACCUM. DPN-BUILDING</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 acc-row">
      <td>COMPUTER</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:orange">
      <td>ACCUM. DPN-COMPUTER</td>
      <td><input class="parentdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="parentcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="3" class="collapse level3 acc-row">
      <td>DPN-COMPUTER 1</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="3" class="collapse level3 acc-row">
      <td>DPN-COMPUTER 2</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:pink">
      <td class="accType">CURRENT ASSETS</td>
      <td><input class="groupdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="groupcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:orange">
      <td>INVESTMENT</td>
      <td><input class="parentdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="parentcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2 acc-row">
      <td>INVESTMENT IN ABC COMPANY</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1 parent-acc-row" style="background-color:orange">
      <td>OTHER INVESTMENT</td>
      <td><input class="parentdr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="parentcr-amount" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2 acc-row">
      <td>OTHER INVESTMENT-ABC COMP</td>
      <td><input class="dr-amount" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="cr-amount" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0" style="background-color:blue">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><input class="dr-total" type="text" disabled></td>
      <td><input class="cr-total" type="text" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, I found some problems from the answer you given. When I add a new row (level 1) at the bottom of the group, it will sum the value to the parent and group. But actually it should only sum to the group as it is in level 1 and it has no child under it. Please check my latest fiddle[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxa5eofd/) . My current result[Image 1](https://postimg.cc/Wdm9Vw53) and my expected result[Image 2](https://postimg.cc/bdG3rhm4)